# Prove that we can connect these points together

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, combinatorial-geometry

There are $n\ge3$ points in the plane.Prove that we can connect these points together by drawing the segments that connect them so that no two segment drawn intersect other than the vertices, and that the final figure will be a polygon with $n$ edges

Attemp: I think we need to have that no $3$ points are collinear.

Consider the convex hull of the $n$ points $P_1P_2\dots P_k, k\leq n$.

We first connect $P_1P_2$ and then we move the line $P_1P_2$ in the direction of the line $P_1P_k$ till it intersects another point $X$(note that it can't intersect $2$ points) and we connect $P_2X$ and then we do the same procedure for the line $P_1X$, and in the end after connecting some point with $P_k$, we connect $P_kP_1$.

Clearly the described algorithm will give a polygon with $n$ vertices where no $2$ non-adjacent edges intersect

Comment: It's not very clear what your question is. I'm assuming you want comments on your proposed proof. You certainly do need that no 3 points are collinear. I don't see the relevance of the convex hull. I'd recommend doing it by induction on $n$ (with $n = 3$ as the base case).

Comment: @RobArthan Why do you need no 3 points collinear? There are plenty of cases with 3 points collinear where it can be done. Of course, there are others where it can't, eg all points collinear.

Comment: @almagest I agree that there are cases with 3 points collinear where a polygon can be drawn. I think the point RobArthan is making is that the stated algorithm requires no 3 points collinear because it claims the moving line "can't intersect 2 points". That claim may be false and so the algorithm might fail.

Comment: The polygon might have to have fewer than $n$ edges if there are 3 collinear points.